# Sitecore client user login failed: You don't have access permission error

Tags: sitecore-client, security, multisite

I installed sitecore 8.2 and after installation I logged in with admin account. Then i followed below procedure to create user and roles.

1) In the User manager I created one user - **tom** (not selected any role at this time, just selected domain as sitecore)

2) in the Role manager created new role (Devteam1).

3) using security editor assigned access rights "Read, Write an Inheritance" for all items in site content tree to Devteam1 role.

So I provided all access rights for Sitecore content,media library,layout etc..

4) Using Access Viewer I verified access right all are allowed in content tree items.

After this am trying to login with user **tom**, but I am getting an error: `You don't have access permission`.

Then using the Security editor I applied access rights for the user also but no luck.

How to resolve this. What am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

All right, your user will not be able to login to Sitecore while your don't assign specific Sitecore's roles. You have to assign at least the `Sitecore Client Users` role for user, so that they can login to Sitecore. With this role, the user can log in to the Sitecore Desktop, but will not have access to any applications.

You can read more about the default Sitecore roles using the link belowk:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/users_roles_and_domains/the_security_roles

UPDATED:

The security roles that you already applied do not provide or restrict access to Sitecore functionality (such as Content Editor, Role Manager, Presentation Manager and etc.), it just restricts the access to items in the content tree, but your user will not be able to see these items unless you allow it by adding corresponding Sitecore roles.

`Sitecore Client Users` allows just login into Sitecore. It can be helpfull when you don't need to provide an access to the content section. Sometimes it's enough. For example, you implemented a custom application, added the icon to the desctop and just want to provide the access only for it.

If you want to allow user managing content, you have to assign the extra `Sitecore Client Authoring` role to the user. If you want to allow managing presentation - `Sitecore Client Designing`

Visit the link above and see which roles are existed in Sitecore and which of them do you need for your needs.

P.S. The better way is inheriting your role from roles above and assigning to the user just your custom role.

Comment: Yes, If i provided Sitecore Client Users role to user, then users are able to login. But what is the use of this role. By default why its not adding to every user in sitecore domain.if i created a user with this role they are not able to access any application or items in site core. They are able to access only sitecore desktop. Then what is the use if i created user with this role.

Comment: I added sitecore client user role then using security editor assigned access rights "Read, Write an Inheritance" for all items in site content tree to Devteam1 role ( custom new role ).But User getting only Sitecore Desktop user not able to access any item.
Then Using security editor assigned access rights "Read, Write an Inheritance" for all items in site content tree to user tom also. 
But no luck after login user getting only sitecore desktop.

Comment: My Quest.. are
After Adding only sitecore client role and using security editor,How to provide access rights for user ?  How to to provide access rights to user from custom role ?

Comment: @nssmonitoring I've updated the answer. Please see and let me know if it is more clear now.

Comment: @nssmonitoring Did my answer help? Does it work as excepted now?